# What data structure would be the least painful DataTable replacement?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, datatable, dataset

I'm storing a lot of sorted ~10 row 2 column/key value pairs in ASP.NET cache-- they're the data for dropdownlists.  Right now they are all DataTables, which isn't very space efficient (the rule of thumb is 10x increase in size when data is stored in a dataset).

Old Code

```
DataTable table = dataAccess.GetDataTable();
dropDownList.DataSource = table;
```

Hoped for new Code

```
Unknown data = dataAccess.GetSomethingMoreSpaceEfficient();
dropDownList.DataSource = data;
```

What pre-existing datastructures are similar enough to DataTable that would minimize code breakage and reduce the serialized size when stored in ASP.NET cache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Key/Value pair or a Dictionary would be more efficient.

Rick Strahl has a nice example http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/32508.aspx

Comment: I agree.  He also mentioned that the data was sorted; the SortedDictionary or SortedList data structure that might be appropriate for the task.

Comment: ah yes. forgot to mention the Ready Sorted flavors!

Comment: I'll have to rename all the columns to "Key" and "Value".  Current code references everything by Column[0], Column["description"], etc. Still, this is an important candidate data structure.

Comment: No need to rename, you would just reference them using "Key" & "Value" as the column names:

Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dic.Add("LGW", "London Gatwick");
dic.Add("MCO", "Orlando Int");

this.drpIATA.DataSource = dic;
this.drpIATA.DataTextField = "Value";
this.drpIATA.DataValueField = "Key";
this.lstStates.DataBind();

Answer (score 0):

Write data to an XML file,based on Session ID, then bind dropdownlists to the XMLDataSource

Comment: That is in effect writing a caching system that stores its objects on the file system instead of in memory.  Any custom rolled caching system wouldn't need me to re-implement cache eviction policies (re-loading from the database from time to time, etc) and UI for on demand cache eviction, which I've already implemented targeting the ASP.NET cache.

Comment: XML could be stored in memory and added to cache w/o a lot of work.

Comment: I think what you need is a good hashing algorithm. SortedDictionary,
Dictionary and SortedList have a lot of performance issues that you can find in Google. It makes your work simple, but does not help you with performance problem.